# Android rotate video post production

Tags: android, camera, rotation, video-processing

on my activity i take a video, and i show it to the user with a surface preview.
In preview, the video is always oriented correctly, because I rotate the preview. But the video is not recorded with the same inclination (but with the default). There is no way to rotate it after you record it, so as to save it to the gallery already rotated (I know it takes time and battery but is a request by the customer)

Answer (score -1):

Use [mp4parser](https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/) library to change the orientation of the whole file.

Use 1.0-RC-24 API for doing this:

```
IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
out.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().setMatrix(Matrix.ROTATE_180);
```

Comment: What is the "result" u see? This is Movie class right? How I can create movie from file path?